# Qt5 tabwidget - addwidget exception thrown read access violation

Tags: c++, qt5, qtabwidget

Creating a tabwidget and adding a tab here...

Sorry I missed this out, creating central widget and the tabwidget:

```
QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget();
QTabWidget* tabWidget = new QTabWidget(centralWidget);
tabWidget->setTabsClosable(false);

this->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);



QWidget* logTab = new QWidget();    
QTextEdit* logOutput = new QTextEdit();
logOutput->setReadOnly(true);
logOutput->setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);
QFont* font = new QFont();
font->setFamily("Courier");
font->setPointSize(10);

QVBoxLayout* tabLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
tabLayout->addWidget(logOutput);
logTab->setLayout(tabLayout);

tabWidget->addTab(logTab, tr("Log"));
```

On the addtab it gives exception thrown read access violation, callstack below:

```
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QTabWidget::insertTab(int index, QWidget * w, const QIcon & icon, const QString & label) Line 472   C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QTabWidget::insertTab(int index, QWidget * w, const QString & label) Line 454   C++
Qt5Widgetsd.dll!QTabWidget::addTab(QWidget * child, const QString & label) Line 399 C++
```

Comment: Please show how you create the tabWidget

Answer (score 0):

I'm double declaring , so there is both a class member variable then a local variable. Doh!!!!!! No wonder it don't work.